# How do I get the nth element from a 2d list in python, to create a new list from those matching nth elements

Tags: python, list, matrix

for example lets say I have the following 2d list:

```
rows = [[1, 7], [3, 9], [5, 11]]
```

and I want a new list like this:

```
columns = [[1, 3, 5], [7, 9, 11]]
```

Basically, if this was a matrix, I want the 'columns'. What's the most pythonic way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: If that's a numpy array, `columns = rows.T`.

Comment: For plain python, `columns = [list(xs) for xs in zip(*rows)]`.

Comment: Okay thanks. I didn't know the terminology. It's called transposing a list?